# returning data async after jquery $.ajax post request in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

After $.ajax post request to the controllers action I would like to get info from the server and then update my partial view, for example I have a list rendered in my view I delete an item from the list using the $.ajax post request and then i would like my list to update itself asynchronously.

Here is my function that deletes the item from the list:

```
 $(".btnDeleteCurrentFavSong").click(function () {

    var songId = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/DeleteCurrentFav/",
        data: { id: songId },
        success: ShowMsg("Song deleted successfully"),
        error: ShowMsg("There was an error therefore song could not be deleted, please try again"),
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Should I somehow redirect to the action on ajax success that returns the list of songs to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your clicked list item looked like this:

```
<li name="120">Artist - Title</li>
```

your javascript could look something like this:

```
$(".btnDeleteCurrentFavSong").click(function () {

    var songId = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/DeleteCurrentFav/",
        data: { id: songId },
        success: function () {
            ShowMsg("Song deleted successfully");
            $("li[name=" + songId + "]").remove();
        },
        error: ShowMsg("There was an error therefore song could not be deleted, please try again"),
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Comment: sweet, didnt think of that! simple and thats what i needed

Comment: here is one possible bug. when user is faster than response and manages to delete some other rows before response is fetched, only last row will be removed, because songId has last value. thats why i suggest to return deleted item id with response and use it instead value that is set in another scope

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the user experience that you wish to give. Convention dictates that a user should be shown the effect of their action. From your example it appears that you are doing this via the `ShowMsg` function. As to whether you should redirect or not, I'm afraid there's nothing authororative out there, do whatever is consistent across your site and would feel natural to users.

Answer (score 0):

option A

- return deleted item id from action
- on success remove deleted item with js

option B

- return partial view from action
- on success replace container with rendered html